# How to convert html tag to styled html? (editorjs)

Tags: javascript, html, editorjs

This is my code for converting editorjs json to html tag.

```js
// store posts
const blogs = [{
    "time": 1641871834196,
    "blocks": [{
      "id": "nwATYHAhq-",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "I wonder&nbsp;"
      }
    }],
    "version": "2.22.2"
  },
  {
    "time": 1641871849493,
    "blocks": [{
      "id": "nwATYHAhq-",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "what is wrong"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "qx4OhycRav",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "with this silly js?"
      }
    }],
    "version": "2.22.2"
  }
]


// retrieve posts
for (var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {

  var getBlocks = blogs[i]['blocks'];
  //console.log('retrieving');
  //console.log(getBlocks);

  for (var y = 0; y < getBlocks.length; y++) {
    console.log('printing text.......');
    console.log(getBlocks[y]);
    var msg = convertDataToHtml(getBlocks);
    console.log(msg);
  }

  var addblog = document.createElement('div');
  var textmsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
  addblog.appendChild(textmsg);
  addblog.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid";
  document.getElementById('allblogs').appendChild(addblog);

  msg = '';

}

function convertDataToHtml(blocks) {
  var convertedHtml = "";
  blocks.map(block => {

    switch (block.type) {
      case "header":
        convertedHtml += `<h${block.data.level}>${block.data.text}</h${block.data.level}>`;
        break;
      case "embded":
        convertedHtml += `<div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="${block.data.embed}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`;
        break;
      case "paragraph":
        convertedHtml += `<p>${block.data.text}</p>`;
        break;
      case "delimiter":
        convertedHtml += "<hr />";
        break;
      case "image":
        convertedHtml += `<img class="img-fluid" src="${block.data.file.url}" title="${block.data.caption}" /><br /><em>${block.data.caption}</em>`;
        break;
      case "list":
        convertedHtml += "<ul>";
        block.data.items.forEach(function(li) {
          convertedHtml += `<li>${li}</li>`;
        });
        convertedHtml += "</ul>";
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Unknown block type", block.type);
        break;
    }
  });
  return convertedHtml;

}
```

```html
<div id="allblogs"></div>
```

Then I have no idea how to convert html tag to styled html.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var msg = parser.parseFromString(msg, 'text/html');
```

I have tried this, but it comes [object HTMLDocument]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to provide us with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Just add as HTML before creating text elements

```
  var addblog = document.createElement('div');
  var textmsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
  document.getElementById('html').innerHTML += msg; // add as HTML
```

```js
// store posts
const blogs = [{
    "time": 1641871834196,
    "blocks": [{
      "id": "nwATYHAhq-",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "I wonder&nbsp;"
      }
    }],
    "version": "2.22.2"
  },
  {
    "time": 1641871849493,
    "blocks": [{
      "id": "nwATYHAhq-",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "what is wrong"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "qx4OhycRav",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "with this silly js?"
      }
    }],
    "version": "2.22.2"
  }
]


// retrieve posts
for (var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {

  var getBlocks = blogs[i]['blocks'];

  for (var y = 0; y < getBlocks.length; y++) {
    var msg = convertDataToHtml(getBlocks);
  }

  var addblog = document.createElement('div');
  var textmsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
  document.getElementById('html').innerHTML += msg; // add as HTML
  addblog.appendChild(textmsg);
  addblog.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid";
  document.getElementById('allblogs').appendChild(addblog);
  msg = '';
}
  

function convertDataToHtml(blocks) {
  var convertedHtml = "";
  blocks.map(block => {

    switch (block.type) {
      case "header":
        convertedHtml += `<h${block.data.level}>${block.data.text}</h${block.data.level}>`;
        break;
      case "embded":
        convertedHtml += `<div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="${block.data.embed}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`;
        break;
      case "paragraph":
        convertedHtml += `<p>${block.data.text}</p>`;
        break;
      case "delimiter":
        convertedHtml += "<hr />";
        break;
      case "image":
        convertedHtml += `<img class="img-fluid" src="${block.data.file.url}" title="${block.data.caption}" /><br /><em>${block.data.caption}</em>`;
        break;
      case "list":
        convertedHtml += "<ul>";
        block.data.items.forEach(function(li) {
          convertedHtml += `<li>${li}</li>`;
        });
        convertedHtml += "</ul>";
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Unknown block type", block.type);
        break;
    }
  });
  return convertedHtml;

}
```

```html
<div id="allblogs"></div>
<div id="html"></div>
```